# O365 Modern authentication with Java Spring Context

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

I have to use oAuth2 "modern authentication" in Java Spring Context and found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424550/ews-java-apis-using-oauth2). Java code I could use.

The getAccessToken() method has however a parameter of type `ManagedExecutorService` and I don't have any idea, what kind of value it should be.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public String getAccessToken(final String clientId, final String clientSecret, final ManagedExecutorService service)
        throws MalformedURLException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
    final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (accessToken != null && now < expiryTimeMs - REFRESH_BEFORE_EXPIRY_MS) {

        final AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, false, service);
        final AuthenticationCallback<AuthenticationResult> callback = new AuthenticationCallback<>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final AuthenticationResult result) {
                log.info("received token");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(final Throwable exc) {
                throw new RuntimeException(exc);
            }
        };

        log.info("requesting token");
        final Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(RESOUCE,
                new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret), callback);

        // wait for access token
        final AuthenticationResult result = future.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // cache token and expiration
        accessToken = result.getAccessToken();
        expiryTimeMs = result.getExpiresAfter();
    }

    return accessToken;
}
```

I put already all necessary dependencies into the project but can't test the method until I know what `ManagedExecutorService`is and where do I get the parameter from.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using one of Spring REST clients which can handle OAuth2 out of the box?

All of `@FeignClient`, `RestTemplate` and `WebClient` expose configuration properties for acquiring access-token from OAuth2 authorization-server using client-credentials (or directly set authorization header if you are processing an authorized request and want to forward incoming access-token).

Choose one of existing clients and read its manual.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. I need to authorize for Microsoft O365 mail. Is there maybe any example for such setup?